# Angular js Update a div without updating the whole page

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Please i want to update a specific div in my view instead of reloading the whole page. 
This is my Script.

```
$scope.submitComment = function() {
    $http({
        url: "comment",
        method: "POST",
        data: $.param($scope.commentData),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.loading = true;
        //location.reload();
        $scope.loading = false;
    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Sorry an error occured');
    });
};
```

This is my view

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
     <br> <br> <br> <br>

<form ng-submit="submitComment()" id="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="author">Author: </label>
    <input id="author" class="form-control " type="text" ng-model="commentData.author" name="author" placeholder="Enter author">
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="message">Message:</label> @{{ commentData.message }}
  <textarea id="message" class="form-control" ng-model="commentData.message" name="message" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="form-group pull-right">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-comment-o">&nbsp;Comment</i></button>
  <!-- <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Comment"> -->
  </div>
</form>
```

```
<h2>Comments</h2> <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    <div><strong>@{{ comment.author }}</strong></div>
    <div>@{{ comment.message }} <button type="button" ng-click="deleteComment(comment.id)" class="btn btn-danger-outline btn-sm" id="submit">Delete</button></div>
   <br>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to update my form so that the text in it goes. and also update my comments as well. I need a help on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `$scope.submitComment()` method, `$http.success()`, you need to `$scope.comments.push($scope.commentData)` and you should be good to go.

```
$scope.submitComment = function() {
    $http({
        // ...
    }).success(function(response) {
        $scope.comments.push($scope.commentData);
    });
};
```

Comment: No error in console but either the page nor the comments are refreshing

Comment: Then make sure `.success()` is actually getting called. Use a break point or a console.log. Check your debugger for the response from the server.

Comment: the console says `Object {data: Array[5], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"} Object {success: true}`     Looks like everything works fine but i dnt know why the page is not refreshing

Comment: woow..It worked..  but how can i take the text in my form out of it..?

Comment: Simply set `$scope.commentData = ''`